# How do I open a file in my IOS SwiftUI App?

Tags: import, swiftui, xcode11, file-sharing

I have an app that saves data in my Documents directory. It would be very useful to be able to mail the data file to some other users so they can also use the gathered information. I have spent most of today looking for a solution, but have not found any answers basic enough to be of any help. So, I would greatly appreciate some help to get me started. Like, what do I need to do to make IOS aware that I am interested in opening ( in my case actually only copying the file to the app’s Documents directory for further chewing) a file with, for example the .xyz-extension and how this is done.

Much appreciated,
stalle

Comment: To simplify the matter and eliminate problems with incorrectly specified UTI’s, I decided to start with simple .txt-files. Info.plist Document Types name=text, UTI=public.plain-text, CFBundleTypeRole=Editor and LSHandlerRank=Alternate.  Now, the app opens as expected from a .txt-file, the first of the URLContexts url reads .../Documents/Inbox/testdata.txt but my Inbox-directory is empty??? What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running on a real device, there seems to be no problem.